# plpgsql error: syntax error at or near ":"

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, plpgsql

I am receiving the error in the title. The weird thing for me is that there is no colon anywhere in my SQL code.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION "CreateUser" (
  "@first_name"           VARCHAR(25),
  "@last_name"            VARCHAR(25),
  "@email"                VARCHAR(254),
  "@password"             VARCHAR(250)
)
RETURNS UUID AS
$func$
DECLARE "id" UUID;
BEGIN
  "id" = uuid_generate_v4();
  INSERT INTO
    "users" (
      "id",
      "first_name",
      "last_name",
      "email",
      "password"
    )
  VALUES (
    "id",
    "@first_name",
    "@last_name",
    "@email",
    "@password"
  );
  RETURN "id";
END;
$func$ LANGUAGE PLPGSQL;
```

The field types are all the same so it can't be a type issue.

Is there a semicolon missing somewhere or is this just structure incorrectly altogether?

Comment: Hmm, you have a variable and a column with the same name it seems, `"id"`? Maybe not the cause of the actual problem but they may clash. Better rename the variable.

Comment: Try and use `VARCHAR(255)` as a default and only restrict that if you have a very compelling reason. For many things, like names and email addresses, shorter fields can cause huge hassles for your users. `VARCHAR(25)` is comically short.

Comment: @stickybit I tried the id name change and the error remained the same. A name over 25 characters would be really long, what is the likelihood of that ever happening?

Comment: The likelihood? 100%. Just ask someone who's Portuguese, Indian or even Spanish.

Comment: Okay, I can change that no problem, easy fix. The error still persists (since I am just inputting test data that fit for sure).

Comment: I also hope those passwords are treated with a password-specific hash like [Bcrypt](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bcrypt) and aren't just dumped in plain-text. Stored procedures like this are usually a huge red flag because this should be handled in the application layer where proper validation, cleaning, and hashing can be performed.

Comment: For what it's worth when I run that code on Postgres 10.4 I do not get any errors.

Comment: @tadman I am storing using bcrypt, so that's not an issue. That's what I found odd. I an adding this to my database through dbBeaver and there are no errors there. When I send a request through postman, I receive the titled error in the command line.

Comment: I used the `psql` command-line tool. I'd confirm it errors out there before going further as this could be an issue with dbBeaver.

Comment: @tadman: there is no advantage using `varchar(255)` over `varchar` or `varchar(500)`

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Depending on your database it does matter, but 255 as a good default minimum is better than something super short like 25.

Comment: @tadman: the DBMS used is Postgres. But that's not really important. 
255 has no special meaning and is not "better" or "worse" than 250 or 260 in any modern DBMS

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that I do not have the package `uuid_generate_v4();` setup on sql and not sure how to support it so at least for the time being, I created a uuid on the server and passed it into sql.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION "CreateUser" (
  "@newid"                UUID,
  "@first_name"           VARCHAR(25),
  "@last_name"            VARCHAR(25),
  "@email"                VARCHAR(254),
  "@password"             VARCHAR(250)
)
RETURNS UUID AS
$func$
DECLARE "id" UUID;
BEGIN
  INSERT INTO
    "users" (
      "id",
      "first_name",
      "last_name",
      "email",
      "password"
    )
  VALUES (
    "@newid",
    "@first_name",
    "@last_name",
    "@email",
    "@password"
  );
  RETURN "id";
END;
$func$ LANGUAGE PLPGSQL;
```

Comment: Use `CREATE EXTENSION "uuid-ossp";` to have `uuid_generate_v4()` available.

Comment: @stickybit where in the function can I place that?

Comment: @Bardon: Nowhere in the function. This installs the extension to the database, that'll bring `uuid_generate_v4()`. Just execute it.